# Implicit differentiation and higher order

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have 2 doubts here ...

First - implicit differentiation

$y= (4-5x^2)^{1/2} $ show that $y^3\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} +20 = 0$

Yes , I do know how to find the -

First - $-5(4-5x^2)^{-1/2} $

Second - $-25(4-5x^2)^{-3/2} $

As there is that $'-25'$ there . How can I get the 20 ? I'm not too sure how to show it ..

Next

2nd -

Finding nth derivatives - 
Let's use this as an example - 
$f(x)= (1-x)^{-1} $

Yes , when they tell us to calculate 1,2,3,4th order it's easy to find by calculating them one by one . However what if they told us to calculate the 100th . Is there an nth formula that I can easily come out with ?

Comment: You derivatives are incorrect. You need to use chain rule, the $5x^2$ turns into $10x$, not just $5$

Answer (score 0):

Your first query is already answered so i will put up the answer to next doubt. You can see a pattern first derivative is $\frac {-1.-1}{(1-x)^2}$ next derivative is $\frac {-1}{(1-x)^3} $... so the nth derivative is $\frac {(-1)^{n+1}}{(1-x)^{n+1}} $. Also if you want to calculate the nth derivative of product of two differentiable functions of $x $ then you can look up the general leibnitz theorem for  derivative of product of  two functions.

Answer (score 0):

You derivatives are incorrect.
$$\begin{align}&y=(4-5x^2)^{1/2}\\
&y'=\frac12(-10x)(4-5x^2)^{-1/2}=-5x(4-5x^2)^{-1/2}\\
&y''=-5(4-5x^2)^{-1/2}+(-5x)(-10x)(-1/2)(4-5x^2)^{-3/2}\\&=-5(4-5x^2)^{-1/2}-25x^2(4-5x^2)^{-3/2}\end{align}$$

Then,$$y=(4-5x^2)^{1/2}\implies y^2=4-5x^2$$
Now use implicit differentiation twice:
$$y^2=4-5x^2\implies 2y\frac{dy}{dx}=-10x\implies2\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2+2y\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=-10$$

Now substituting the above expressions, $$2(y')^2=2\left(\frac{-5x}{y}\right)^2=\frac{50x^2}{y^2}$$
Putting that back into the above equation, and dividing by 2; $$25x^2+5y^2+y^3y''=0\implies25x^2+(20-25x^2)+y^3y''=0\implies y^3y''+20=0$$
As required

---

For your second query, as the other answer mentions, the Leibniz rule is what to go for.